# encounter error , when building linphone with param `enable_gpl_third_parties=no`

Tags: ios, compilation, linphone

When I build the linphone-iphone SDK with param `enable_gpl_third_parties=no`, but something wrong happened. Error happened capture is below:

[image: error details]

Anybody know how to fix it? Thanks very much!

Comment: Open your target's Build Settings. Locate the Other Linker Flags setting. Add the -lz flag to it. Alternatively you can also add libz.dylib frmework to your project.

Comment: Try posting in linphone mailing list if you have further problem.